# Execute a python script from terminal that reads an input file from a folder and writes an output file in another folder

Tags: bash, terminal

I am trying to write a bash script that reads and input .csv file from a folder, execute a python file and write the output file in .csv in another folder. Such that on terminal you can type somthing like this:

inputFolder\input_file.csv | python script.py > outputFolder\output_file.csv.

How can I do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have anything to work with so far?

Comment: Does the python script expect to read data from stdin, or is it expecting to get a filename argument?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use an input redirection:

```
python script.py < inputFolder/input_file.csv > outputFolder/output_file.csv
```

What OS are you using? `\` is the Windows directory separator. Linux uses `/`

Comment: You should stick to either `camelCase` or `snake_case` but don't mix the two styles.